# signal: killed at the end of function

Tags: go, go-gin

Using go-gin I have this function to receive posted jokes and saved them to database:

```
func PostJoke(c *gin.Context) {
    var err error

    userId, userName, userAvatar := shared.GetUserInfo(c)

    if userId == 0 {
        c.JSON(403, gin.H{"error": "not authorized"})
    }

    title := c.PostForm("title")
    content := c.PostForm("content")
    nsfwSt := c.PostForm("nsfw")
    nsfw, err := strconv.Atoi(nsfwSt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "internal server error"})
    }

    file, err := c.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("get form err: %s", err.Error()))
        return
    }
    dir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    filename := path.Join(shared.RandString(6) + path.Ext(file.Filename))
    dest := dir + "/media/photos/" + filename
    if err := c.SaveUploadedFile(file, dest); err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("upload file err: %s", err.Error()))
        return
    }
    _, err = shared.Dbmap.Exec("INSERT INTO joke (user_id, username, user_avatar, title, content, photo, nsfw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", userId, userName, userAvatar, title, content, filename, nsfw)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "internal server error"})
    }

    fmt.Println("end of function")
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"sccess": "joke is created"})

}
```

The function works as expected: saves the data and returns `"sccess": "joke is created"`
However at the end I receive this mysterious error at the terminal:

```
signal: killed
```

and does not respond anymore.

I'm wondering what can cause this and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:** 
`go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64`

and here is my `go env`:

```
me@pc:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/me/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build842411537=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

When I try to rebuild all packages using `sudo go install -a`
, I get:

```
main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
main.go:9:2: cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "proj/controller" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/proj/controller (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
main.go:5:2: cannot find package "proj/middleware" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/proj/middleware (from $GOROOT)
    ($GOPATH not set)
```

Comment: What version of go are you using? `go env` ?

Comment: @captncraig Just added the go env.

Comment: and `go version`? A lot of similar reports seem to recommend upgrading to go 1.8.1+

Comment: go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64

Comment: Though you shouldn't have to, can you try a `go install -a` for your project to make sure all your deps are re-built correctly?

Comment: @JimB when I run the command without `sudo`, i.e `$ go install -a` I get 
`go install runtime/internal/sys: open /usr/local/go/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/internal/sys.a: permission denied`. Could it be a cause of the problem?  Also note that the run command that causes singal killed is `go-reload -a main.go`. When I use `go build && ./proj` I do not get the `signal killed` issue.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the error is in the function and not just after it returns?

Comment: @MiloChristiansen No I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Karlom: rebuild or reinstall your Go installation first. If `go-reload` is the faulty binary, you need to rebuild that too.

Comment: go-reload seems to be a shell script that kills the old process and starts the new one. This is almost certainly your problem, your own code is *probably* fine. See [go-reload](https://github.com/alexedwards/go-reload/blob/master/go-reload)

Comment: @JimB please have a look at to the result of  `sudo go install -a` which I just added to the question.

Comment: @Karlom: don't build things with sudo. It's easier if you can write to GOROOT as a normal user, otherwise limit the user of sudo to building the go installation. You also have either set GOROOT or have a multiple Go installations, because your GOROOT is different between the sudo command and your first command. Never set GOROOT unless you know you have to, and make sure you aren't accessing the `go` tools from multiple paths.

Comment: In some cases you do error check and then log error if it is exist, but do not do `return`. Don't think it is a cause of your issue, but still.